# Why is the flight path from Taipei to Tianjin not a straight line?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, china, taiwan

The flight path from Taipei, Taiwan, to Tianjin, China, does not go directly to Tianjin in a straight line.

Instead, it heads directly north, then banks left (west) before heading north again.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Please note that [cross-posting is not an acceptable practice on the StackExchange network](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/260382). Virtually all questions that are written properly and have been thought through will have a single site where they are most suitable. In this case, your [cross-post to Aviation](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22633) is the most suitable site as they are more qualified to answer this type of question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has already been cross-posted to another site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because China manages its air traffic by routing flights along relatively narrow air corridors.  For a discussion, see https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/explained-flight-delays-china-todd-siena.

Comment: Thank you very much, that explains it very clearly! I don't suppose anyone knows why the flight corridors are so small? Is it something to do with military air space?

Comment: I suspect it is historical.  They were probably established decades ago and the ATC system has not been modernized.